# how to i get models id from onclick

Tags: python, django

Hi i am new to django and trying to build a zomato like site.i want to poplulate a restaurants menu on click on the restaurant button.i have Business model where all restaurants data is saved and menu model where menu of a restaurants is saved with restaurant name as a foreign key , i have populated the restaurants to the home.html, how do i populate menu of specific restaurants into store.html after click on a specific restaurant hope i'm asking the right question
here is  my code

models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
bname=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
specialities=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
location=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
# image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.bname

@property
def imageURL(self):

    try:
        url=self.image.url
    except:
        url= ''
    return url

class Menu(models.Model):
    business=models.ForeignKey(Business,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=False)
    dish_name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    price=models.IntegerField(null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.dish_name
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
businesses= Business.objects.all()
context={'businesses':businesses}

return render(request,"foodapp/home.html",context)

def store(request):
    menus=Menu.objects.get.all()
    context={'menus':menus}
    return render(request,"foodapp/store.html",context)
```

home.html

```
    {% for business in businesses %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="box-element product">
    <img  class="thumbnail" src="{% static 'images/assets/placeholder.png' %}" alt="">
    <hr>
    <h6><strong>{{business.bname}}</strong></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>{{business.specialities}}</h6>
    <h6>{{business.location}} &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button data-product={{business.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add- 
     btn update-cart">
            <a href="{% url 'store' %}"> View</a></button>
     </h6>
    {% endfor %}
```

store.html

```
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
<div class="container">  
    {% for menus in menu %}   
<div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="box-element product">
    <img  class="thumbnail" src="{% static 'images/assets/placeholder.png' %}" alt="">
    <hr>
    <h6><strong>{{menu.dish_name}}</strong></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Type:</h6>
    <button data-product={{}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update- 
    cart">
        <a href="{% url 'cart' %}"> Add to Cart</a></button>        
    
        
    <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right;">{{menu.price}}</h4>
    </div>
  

    </div>
   {% endfor %}
 
   </div>



 {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `urls.py` to accept an id along with `store` ex: `store/1` and in your `home.html` change url from `<a href="{% url 'store' %}"> View</a></button>` to `<a href="{% url 'store' business.id %}"> View</a></button>`

Urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('store/<int:id>/', views.store),
    # ...
]
```

Views.py

```py
def store(request, id):
    menus=Menu.objects.filter(business_id=id)
    context={'menus':menus}
    return render(request,"foodapp/store.html",context)
```

and fix the mistake from store.html:`{% for menus in menu %}` to `{% for menu in menus %}`